# I'm getting an error message: _tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "ButtonLeft"

Tags: python, events, python-turtle

My code:

```
def left():
    a.bk(25)
def right():
    a.fd(25)
def up():
    a.lt(90)
    a.fd(25)
    a.rt(90)
def down():
    a.rt(90)
    a.fd(25)
    a.lt(90)
while True:
    a.onrelease(left,"Left")
    a.onrelease(right,"Right")
    a.onrelease(up,"Up")
    a.onrelease(down,"Down")
    a.listen()
```

How do I fix this? I'd also prefer to use onkey instead of onrelease but it gives me an error message: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'onkey'

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: you should define `a.onrelease(...)` only once - you don't have to use it inside look `while True` because it may assign the same function many times. And I think you don't need `while`loop at all. You many need only `a.mainloop() `

Comment: `onrelease` is for mouse buttons not for keys, and it uses button's number - 1 (left button), 2 (right button), 3 (middle button). For keyboard's keys you should use `onkeyrelease` or `onkey`. Read documentation for [turtle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onkey)

Comment: keyboard's keys are not assigned to turtles so you should use directly `turtle.onkey()` and `turtle.listen()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onrelease()`, `onclick()`, `ondrag()` are for mouse's buttons - and it needs numbers `1` (left button), `2` (middle button), `3` (right button). Probably it may also use `4` and `5` if mouse has more buttons. They are assigned to turtles and they need `a.onrelease()`

`onkey()`, `onkeyrelease()`, `onkeypress()` are for keyboard's keys - but keys are not assigned to turtles and you should use directly `turtle.onkey()` or you should create `screen = turtle.Screen()` and use `screen.onkey()`

And you don't have to run code in `while`-loop but use `turtle.mainloop()` or `turtle.done()`.

```
import turtle

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions before main code

def left():
    a.bk(25)
    
def right():
    a.fd(25)
    
def up():
    a.lt(90)
    a.fd(25)
    a.rt(90)
    
def down():
    a.rt(90)
    a.fd(25)
    a.lt(90)

def turle_clicked(x, y):
    print('turtle:', x, y)

def screen_clicked(x, y):
    print('screen:', x, y)

# --- main ---

a = turtle.Turtle()

a.onrelease(turle_clicked, 1)  # left button (clicked on turtle)
a.onrelease(turle_clicked, 2)  # middle button (clicked on turtle)
a.onrelease(turle_clicked, 3)  # right button (clicked on turtle)

turtle.onscreenclick(screen_clicked, 1)  # left button  (clicked in any place in window)

turtle.onkey(left,"Left")
turtle.onkey(right,"Right")
turtle.onkey(up,"Up")
turtle.onkey(down,"Down")
        
turtle.listen()

turtle.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)